# What does the pronoun "en" refer to in the sentence "J'en ai des frissons dans le dos"?

Tags: pronoms, antécédent

> « Quand je repense à ce qui est arrivé sur cette île... **J'en ai** des frissons dans le dos. »
>
> vs « **J'ai** des frissons dans le dos. »

I understand that the pronoun "**en**" is used to replace a "**de ...**" expression in a previous context, but I cannot see exactly what the "**en**" in this particular sentence refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> J'en ai des frissons dans le dos.

Can be translated

> *This* gives me shivers.

The "en" has the same function as *this* in this translation.

Using "de" we could write

> J'ai des frissons dans le dos *à cause de* ce truc.

To give more details, a better way of saying it would be :

> Ce truc me donne des frissons dans le dos.

The only cases where you could directly use "de" are when you specify the kind of shivers :

> J'ai des frissons de fièvre (Fever)

Even then, it's not the best way to use it. If you can, stick to the "Ce truc" structure.

Comment: Thanks. If you choose to leave "en" out and use the "de ..." form instead, how would you rephrase this sentence? « J'ai des frissons dans le dos **de cela {from this}**. » ?

Comment: "Ça me donne des frissons dans le dos" plustôt ou bien "ça me fait frissoner dans le dos".

Answer (score 0):

« Quand je repense à ce qui est arrivé sur cette île... J'en ai des frissons dans le dos » = j'ai des frissons dans le dos venant de cette pensée. La provenance des frissons est explicite.

« J'ai des frissons dans le dos » est aussi correct ; on se doute bien que c'est cette pensée qui donne des frissons dans le dos, mais ce n'est pas explicite.

When you see "en", think "de cela" or "de ce qui vient d'être évoqué". Unlike in your example, "en" is often compulsory. Example:

Voici des bonbons - J'en veux ! (not: Je veux !)

Here are some candies - I want some! (not: I want!)